# Не изменяется значение указателя

Tags: c++, указатели

```
void f(int *b) {
b = new int;
*b = 2;
}

int main() {

int *a = NULL;
f(a);

if (a == NULL) {
    std::cout << "mde";
}

return 0;
}
```

Объясните, пожалуйста, почему в данном коде переменная `a` попрежнему осталась `NULL`? Ведь указатель - это адресс на область памяти. Изначально он никуда не указывает. Потом я передаю адресс на эту облась памяти и туда уже что-то записываю и она не изменяется. Объясните, пожалуйста, почему?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Потому что вы передаете указатель a по значению, а не по ссылке. То есть, внутри функции f b - это копия указателя a. И то, что вы туда записываете новый адрес a никак не затрагивает.

Если вам нужно именно модифицировать a, сделайте так (вариант со ссылкой):

```
void f(int*&b)
{
    b = new int;
    *b = 2;
}
```

или так (вариант с указателем):

```
void f(int **b)
{
    *b = new int;
    **b = 2;
}
```

Во втором случае, вызов f надо поменять: не f(a); а f(&a);

Answer (score 4):

При передаче параметра в функцию *по значению* создается *копия*.

```
void f(int *b) { // в b копируется переданное значение  
    b = new int; // в b заносится новый адрес
    *b = 2;
}                // при выходе b уничтожается
```

Так что то, что вы поработали с **копией** `a`, на значение `a` никак не влияет.

Вам нужно (раз это C++) использовать *ссылку* на указатель:

```
void f(int* &b) {
    b = new int;
    *b = 2;
}
```

Тогда результат работы сохранися в `a`.

Или передавать указатель на указатель:

```
void f(int**b) {
    *b = new int;
    **b = 2;
}

int *a = NULL;
f(&a);
```