# Не обнуляется указатель

Tags: c, функции

Требуется написать функции выделения памяти и её очищения. Функция очистки памяти должна быть вида `erase (указатель на область памяти)`. Написал в следующем виде, но после выполнения функции erase указатель `с` до сих пор хранит не нулевой адрес.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int* create (int size)
{
    int *p;
    p = (int*) malloc (size*sizeof(int));
    if (p == NULL)
    {
        perror ("Allocation error");
        return NULL;
    }
    return p;
}

void erase (int *p)
{
    printf ("POINTER: %p\t", p);
    if (p != NULL) free (p);
    p = NULL;
}

int main (void)
{
    int *c = NULL;
    c = create (7);
    erase (c);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *"после выполнения функции erase указатель с до сих пор хранит не нулевой адрес"* - все работает как ожидается, ведь после выполнения `c = create (7);` вы никогда не присваиваете указателю `c` нулевое значение.

Comment: Почему указатель не обнуляется в функции erase?

Comment: В функции `erase` обнуляется указатель `p`.

Comment: Как обнулить указатель 'с' из функции erase?

Comment: Передавать туда указатель на этот указатель.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/756830/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F

Answer (score 5):

Функция не может обнулить указатель - Вы передаете ей его по значению. Считайте, что значение указателя "копируется". Что бы сделать возможным, то, что Вы хотите, есть два способа.

1. Передавать указатель на указатель.

   ```
   void erase(int** p)
   {
       printf ("POINTER: %p\t", *p);
       free (*p);
       *p = NULL;
   }
   ```

   ну и вызывать так `erase(&c);`
2. Использовать немного макросов.

   ```
   void private_erase (int *p)
   {
       printf ("POINTER: %p\t", p);
       free (p);
   }

   #define erase(p) {private_erase(p); p = NULL;}
   ```

вызов при этом не поменяется.

free нормально работает с NULL указателем. Дополнительная проверка не нужна.

Answer (score -2):

Вам нужно передавать ссылку на указатель.

Comment: В С нет ссылок.

Comment: некоторые люди путают оператор взятия адреса и ссылку. Как и си и плюсы.

Comment: Ох, извиняюсь, проглядел отсутствие плюсов)